# Regex to Validate GSTIN Number

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core-1.0

How to Validate GSTIN Number using regex.
eg.11ABCDE1234L1Z1

My current regex is:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}‌​)+$
```

Comment: would be helpful to link to any documentation that explains what makes a valid GSTIN Number!

Comment: I am using following but not working what i exactly want.


                ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$

Comment: My Requirementis as follows:
  -First two character sholud be numeric like;01,02-09,10--27,29-37 but 28 
     not included
-   5 alphbets
-4 digits
-1 alphabets
-1 digit
- 1 aplhabets
-1 digist

Answer (score 4):

Last digit is **check digit**. There is not much clarity on the internet on its validation - based on some real GSTIN examples - its alphanumeric - `0-9A-Z`

The correct regex is therefore -

```
^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the most accepted Regex for GSTIN Number.

```
/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the requirements in the comment section, this is what I came up with.

([01]\d|[2][0-79]|[3][0-7])[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}\d[A-Z]{1}\d

Answer (score 0):

how about this one?

`\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}L\dZ\d`

Answer (score 0):

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rPan =
                        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$");

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering question is good but your answer here just repeats the regular expression in existing and it has no explanation. Answers like this have no real value as they do not give any useful extra information. Please read the [help] pages about how to write good and useful answers.